# Using SimpleFormController

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I have a controller which accepts a form post -

```
@Controller
public class RegistrationFormController extends SimpleFormController {
.....
.....
    @RequestMapping(value="index", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    protected ModelAndView onSubmit(@ModelAttribute Registration registration) throws Exception {
        String uname=registration.getUsername();
        .....
    .......

         ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("success");
.....
......
          mv.addObject("addr",addr);

        return mv;
    }
```

Thsi would work just as well even if i do not extend SimpleFormController.
What then can I gain by extending?

Comment: `SimpleFormController` is a `Controller` not a `@Controller`. The `SimpleFormController` is deprecated as of Spring 3 in favor of annotation based controllers. Extending it could (and in my experience will) lead to problems due to the different processing/handling of `Controller` and `@Controller` classes. So when using annotions and extending this class you gain nothing (well maybe some strange and weird issues in the long run).

Answer (score 1):

Well, the setup seems not good. The `@Controller` annotation is a nice feature which is used for declaring stereotypes. It just says that it is another spring `Component` or Spring managed bean and can be detected in component scan.

Where as when you extend `SimpleFormController` you explicitly say that it is a Controller and it has to be used as a controller, it will be used to accept submitted form data and return a response in form of a view.

The two notations in the same class makes no sense at all, I feel that making a class `SimpleFormController` restricts it from using any method name and you are forced to use a `onSubmit` method. Whereas, if you use `@Controller` you leverage all the flexibility in Spring 3 and above.